# build does not stop in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build, projects-and-solutions

I try to build a simple piece of code in Visual Studio, but the building process gets entangled in an infinite loop.

The code is simple:

```
// test.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include <iostream.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    cout << "Hi." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea what is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: What's in your `stdafx.h`? And at what stage during the build does it get stuck? preprocessing, compiling or linking?

Comment: I made the code even simpler now. It is not working....

Comment: Ok, so I rewrote the simple code example. How can I find our what stage the code is stuck?

Comment: `stdafx.h` is some stupid pre-compiled that VS keeps pushing you to add when making a new project. I've seen it cause trouble before.

Answer (score 0):

spot several things:

1. not sure what's in 'stdafx.h'
2. #include < iostream >
3. std::cout, std::endl (unless using namespace std; somewhere)

Build works fine for me, though.

Comment: I forgot the namespace indeed -- I corrected the example. But is not working properly.